# Pre populating an email in an html form after an employee id is inputted

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I just started learning jsp and i came across a particular problem. i have been trying to prepopulate my html from by getting the email from the database. The employee needs to input their employee id and depending on the employee id the email is sent to the form

I have tried to send the employee id using jstl, ut i have failed i always get an error saying employee id is null, maybe i dont understand the logic behind sending the employe id using servlets or jstl

user-registration.jsp

```
<div class="regtop">
<h2>User Registration</h2>
</div>  
       <!--  <form action="RegisterControllerServlet">  -->
     <c:url var="templink" value="RegisterControllerServlet">
      <c:param  name="command" value="LOAD"/>

     </c:url>
  <div class="container">

    <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
    <hr>

     <label for="email"><b>Enter employee id</b></label>
    <input type="text"  name="u_eid"  >


    <a href="${templink}" >Get email</a>
    <br>
    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text"  name="email" value="${THE_USER.email}">
```

RegisterControllerServlet.java

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        try {
            //read the "command" parameter
            String theCommand=request.getParameter("command");

            //if the command is missing,then default to listing pharmacists
            //route to the appropriate method
            switch(theCommand)
            {

            case "LOAD":
                loadUser(request,response);
                break;

            }



    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        throw new ServletException(e);
    }

}
    private void loadUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {


        String eid=request.getParameter("u_eid");

        Employee themp=registerDbutil.getUser(eid);

        //plaqce user in the request attribute
                request.setAttribute("THE_USER", themp);


        //send to jsp page:update -user-reg.jsp 
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher=
                        request.getRequestDispatcher("/user registartion.jsp");
                dispatcher.forward(request,response);

    }
```

RegisterDbUtil.java

```
public Employee getUser(String eid) throws Exception{

        Employee theuser=null;

        Connection myConn =null;
        PreparedStatement myStmt=null;
        ResultSet myRs=null;

        try
        {
        //get connection to db
        myConn=dataSource.getConnection();


        //create sql to get selected user email
        String sql="select email from employee where eid=? ";   

        //create prepared statements
        myStmt=myConn.prepareStatement(sql);
        myStmt.setString(1, eid);


        //execute state
        myRs=myStmt.executeQuery();


        if(myRs.next())
        {
            String email=myRs.getString("email");


            theuser=new Employee(email);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not find employee id:" +eid);
        }


        return theuser;
    }finally
        {
        close(myConn,myStmt,null);
    }

}
```

I expect the output to prepopulate the html form of the employee when the employee id is inputted

Answer (score 0):

It's null because when you click on the link to `RegisterControllerServlet` you are not passing the employee id as a parameter:

```
  <c:url var="templink" value="RegisterControllerServlet">
      <c:param  name="command" value="LOAD"/>
  </c:url>
```

You need to add the employee id as a parameter inside this JSTL url tag... But because you want the user to write the employee id in an input field, you need to use the form tag, not the JSTL url tag (because you don't know what the employee id will be).

```
     <!--  <c:url var="templink" value="RegisterControllerServlet">
      <c:param  name="command" value="LOAD"/>
     </c:url>  -->

  <div class="container">

    <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
    <hr>
  <form action="RegisterControllerServlet">
     <label for="email"><b>Enter employee id</b></label>
    <input type="text"  name="u_eid"  >

    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text"  name="email" value="${THE_USER.email}">

    <input type="submit" name="command" value="LOAD"/> 
</form>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you i will give it a try